# Server.Mappath() fail on remote server

Tags: c#, localhost, remote-server

i use like this codes for prepare paths.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/"+ User.Identity.Name+ "/file.zip");
```

i take this error when i run this code on localhost

```
 Index:582 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/trkmml/Documents/GitHub/OfisTakip/trkmml/file.zip
```

**i think its not problem (its chrome security thing). anyway file path is correct.**

On the other hand, when I upload the program to hosting, it adds "file:///C:/Inetpub/vhosts" to the front of the link. how can i cancel this part. how do I make it just

```
http://example.com/httpdocs/trkmml/file.zip".
```

here is error on remote host

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Inetpub/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/trkmml/file.zip
```

Comment: Server.MapPath will give you the physical path of a resource on the server. If you can share how you utilize (where do you use) the resulting path, someone can help

Comment: returned path(string) from controller to jquery get function and here i use `document.getElementById('indir_iframe').src = path;` for download file

Comment: Ok, just use `string path = Request.ApplicationPath + "/" + User.Identity.Name + "/file.zip"`. This will prepare a path like `"/httpdoc/trkmml/file.zip"` and it should work on the client. This should work for both your local system and on the hosting service. Please remember that, when your site is running as root, Request.ApplicationPath returns `"/"`. You should take necessary actions if this is so, but just try this for now, and it should work

Comment: it's run like a charm. Çok teşekkür ederim :)

Comment: You're welcome. Rica ederim.